# Get process variable

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Given a process id, is it possible to connect to a Python process (launched from another interpreter instance) and retrieve user-defined variable values?

I'd like to get the progress from a worker process. The mechanisms described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) (`Value`, `Array`) seem to assume communication between parent process (i.e. process initiator) and child process only. I could only think of an indirect way by letting the process write its variables to a data storage, but was hoping there's also a more direct way to achieve this. How would the Python code look like that "connects" to other non-child processes to retrieve variable values?

Comment: [Threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) is a module that you can use that gets around the global interpreter lock (namespace). Have you tried it? Also, could you post your code in your OP?

Answer (score 0):

checkout [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/):

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.pids()
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, ..., 32498]
>> psutil.Process(32498).environ()
{}
```